# Why is my integrand wrong?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given the following integral. $$\iiint\limits_E \sqrt{x^2+z^2} \ dV$$ bound by the paraboloid $y=x^2+z^2$ and the plane $y=9$.

Half way through the problem, it says the given integral can be simplified to $$\int_{-3}^3\int_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} {\left(9-x^2-z^2\right)\sqrt{x^2+z^2}} \ dz \ dx$$. I understand how the integral has made it to this point.

However, it says that it is easier to solve by converting to polar coordinates in the xz-plane: $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $z=r\sin{\theta}$.

This is where my understanding ends. This is the end part of the question.

$$\iiint \sqrt{x^2+z^2} \ dV = \iint (9-x^2-z^2)\sqrt{x^2+z^2} \ dA
\\ = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 {\mathrm{integrand \ here}} \ dr \ d\theta$$

This is the part where I am not able to get the question right. Substituting $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $z=r\sin{\theta}$ in the integral, I get the integrated: $\left(9-r^2\right)\cdot\sqrt{r^2} = r\cdot \left( 9-r^2\right)$ as $r\geq 0$.

Where am I wrong in getting $r\cdot \left( 9-r^2\right)$ for the integrand?

Comment: Forgot the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)? $\mathrm{d}A=r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ for polar coordinates.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Hi. I do know what the Jacobian matrix is. However, I do not know how the matrix would be useful in this problem.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Oh. You meant that $dA=r dr d\theta$. Yes, I do know that. Thank you for catching that mistake.

Comment: You're welcome. Does it fit now?)

Comment: You integrate with respect to an infinitesimal area element such as $dA=dxdy$. Now, if you describe $dA$ in polar coordinates, approximate with a part of a triangle or some sort of skewed box.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Yes it does! I can tell you that it is not my first time forgetting to multiply r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to multiply r to the integrand because $\mathrm{d}A=r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$, which would make your integrand to $-\left(r^3-9r\right)\cdot r$.

Comment: How to obtain dA? The small element is at distance $r$ and its width is $dr$. Then its height is $r\sin d\theta\approx rd\theta$. Width and height is the approximate area of this "skewed" box. $dA\approx drd\theta$. Taking the limit and the appromixation limits to an equality.